# Getting the actual values from image.normalizedDifference in Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to display an image after `normalizedDifference` function in Google Earth Engine
but the default is that negative input values are forced to 0 so that the result is confined to the range (-1, 1).
Can I change the default and get the real values from the calculation?

```
def addLSWI(image):# add NDVI band to collection
    return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference([ 'B8','B12',]).rename('LSWI'))

imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");
imageBand_LSWIBand = imageCollection.map(addLSWI)
image_XT = ee.Image(imageBand_LSWIBand.filterDate('2015-10-28','2021-03-30').filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE','equals','36RXT').first());
```

The results from `image_XT.select('LSWI').getInfo()`:

```
{'type': 'Image',
 'bands': [{'id': 'LSWI',
   'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType',
    'precision': 'float',
    'min': -1,
    'max': 1},
```

Comment: Can you share some example code?

Comment: If you use Sentinel 2 data you don't need to use anything else, since S2 input values will never be negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your own normalized difference if you want to allow negative inputs.
It's just (A-B)/(A+B)

```
return image.addBands(image.expression('LSWI = (B8 - B12) / (B8 + B12)', {
     'B8': image.select('B8'),
     'B12': image.select(B12')
})
```